# Practical use of Nested virtualization

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, virtualization

Hey I've just started using GCP and recently I've come across nested virtualization in GCP. 
If you can help me with some **examples where nested virtualization is necessary to implement in a VM**.

Answer (score 2):

Nested virtualization allows two things:

- Run VMs inside VMs: This is useful if you want run a VM and you are already on a VM(google compute engine)
- Run multiple VMs on the same machine: This is useful to reduce costs, or share identical environment between VMs with minimal effort.

[Google itself gives these example use cases:](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-nested-virtualization-for)

> Nested virtualization makes it easier for enterprise users to move
>   their on-premises, virtualized workloads to the cloud without having
>   to import and convert VM images. Dev/test and CI/CD workloads that
>   need to validate software in multiple environments are a good match
>   for nested virtualization. Nested virtualization also enables more
>   cost-effective, cloud-based disaster recovery solutions and is ideal
>   for technical training and certification courses where students need
>   identical environments to practice the exercises.

And a real life customer case, where they are concurrently testing an app on multiple virtual android environments on the same compute engine instance.

> This is a huge win for QA and development teams who need native mobile
>   systems, such as Android, for testing/validating mobile apps. Using
>   Google’s new hardware-accelerated nested virtualization, Functionize
>   now enables QA teams to dramatically reduce costs, time-to-test, and
>   the pain of maintaining a complex device inventory. — Tamas Cser,
>   Founder and CEO, Functionize

Comment: Thank you very much. It has given me a much clearer picture of Nested virtualization implementation.

Comment: great, if this helped you, you can accept this as an answer

Comment: We use it for our dev/test and education use-cases and also for bursting/auto-scaling from on-prem to GCP, when there's a need. It allows us to run our workloads as-is without re-architecting them.